# Wordpress Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected Token Illegal

Tags: wordpress, localhost, admin, local, syntax-error

I have a local install of Wordpress running & I am suddenly getting these errors in my console:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
media-upload.php:75Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
media-upload.php:89Uncaught ReferenceError: SWFUpload is not defined
media-upload.php:156Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
load-scripts.php:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL
```

Non-wordpress site's work fine and I've never had any issues like this before, it seems to be limited to Wordpress.

What I don't understand is that the modal window is being called and loading AJAX content, additionally all the transitions work in the rest of the Wordpress admin area.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Disable magic_quotes_gpc, magic_quotes_runtime, magic_quotes_sybase in PHP administration console or php.ini. [This feature has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0 and REMOVED as of PHP 5.4.0](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc). You can also disable dynamic content compression with IIS administrative console. Then reset your browser cache.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem also, but clearing the browser, cache (Chrome) with SHIFT+F5 had reloaded the scripts and solved the problem. 
Refresh the cache for every page where you encounter the problem.